# r2dbc ReactiveCrudRepository keeps crashing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

My pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>       

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mssql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

My properties looks like:

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:mssql://localhost:1433/Admin
spring.r2dbc.username=xxx
spring.r2dbc.password=xxx
```

Repo looks like:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<MyUser, String> {
    @Query("SELECT u.Username AS username, u.Password as password FROM Users u INNER JOIN Roles r ON u.RoleId=r.Roleid WHERE u.Username=@username") 
    public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

MyUser looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyUser implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public MyUser(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
```

I turned on the SQL profiler and caught the query coming in, and it is 100% correct and returns the correct data, but it seems to be crashing on the deserialization. I set a breakpoint and it never calls the MyUser contructor. If I manually create one with Mono.just(), the app works as expected.

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient$DefaultTypedExecuteSpec.lambda$new$0(DefaultDatabaseClient.java:590) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/login?error" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient$DefaultTypedExecuteSpec.lambda$new$0(DefaultDatabaseClient.java:590) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(BiFunction.java:70) ~[na:na]
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.MssqlResult.lambda$map$2(MssqlResult.java:169) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.4.RELEASE.jar:0.8.4.RELEASE]
```

Any ideas on the what the issue is? The exception is on this block of code:

```
    if (typeToRead.isInterface()) {
        this.mappingFunction = ColumnMapRowMapper.INSTANCE
                .andThen(map -> projectionFactory.createProjection(typeToRead, map));
    } else {
        this.mappingFunction = dataAccessStrategy.getRowMapper(typeToRead);
    }
```

Comment: Can @username be null? And this is why you see NPE

Comment: @username is correct. I verified the query in SQL profiler.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using the Repository, in your codes, `MyUser` is not annotated with `@Table`, eg [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L292)
2. You could try to use `DatabaseClient` to handle the query manually if you do not use the OR Mapping provided in Spring Data R2dbc, it is more flexible if you are stick on writing custom SQL scripts. eg. [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java).

Comment: I tried adding @Table(value="Users") to MyUser. I also tried switching to :username and R2dbcRepository as in your sample. Same exception as above.

Comment: I looked at the DatabaseClient in the sample. Where is it initialized? I got an error saying that .sql was undefined.

Comment: I think you should keep to use `@username` in mssql. By default, I think Spring Boot will detect the parameter bind strategy by URL.

Comment: `DatabaseClient`, `R2dbcEntityTemplate` are also configured in your Spring Boot application, you use them directly.

Comment: Any idea on the null exception with the ReactiveCrudRepository? Was hoping to use that as it fits in the architecture.

Comment: According to your log info, I can not determine the reason for your entity class, try to add `@Transient` to getXXXX if you are not creating columns for them.

Comment: I was trying to get DatabaseClient to work and I stumbled across something that fixed the repo. If I make the repo method public Mono<MyUser> findByUsername(String username); vs. Mono<UserDetails>, then it works! UserDetails is the interface for MyUser. I do have to cast it to Mono<UserDetails> with .map() in the service layer... but it finally works! :) Not sure if that gives you a hint? Every sample I saw seemed to show that you can use the interface on the return?

Comment: In the design view, I would like to use a simple user entity for our business and convert it to Spring Security's `UserDetails` in [a user details service bean](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-jwt-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/config/SecurityConfig.java#L60-l72). Thus our user is never coupled with `UserDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a default constructor (a constructor with no parameters) to your MyUser class.

Comment: I tried adding a default constructor, same exception. I ran the SQL profiler and the query is 100% correct and the correct data is being returned.

Comment: It doesn't hit either constructor.